# AWS - How to activate IAM user and role access to the Billing via boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, billing

Dos anyone know how to activate IAM user and role access to the Billing and Cost Management via boto3.
In the documentation this is possible for new users in an organization, but I couldn't find information for an existing non org account

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirement? Are you wanting to create an IAM User and assign them permissions? This can certainly be done via boto3. What have you tried and what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Activating IAM user access to the Billing and Cost Management console [can only be done using AWS console](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-billing-access/) as root. So at least once, you have to login as the root. Once you activate the access, then you use regular boto3 tools to add IAM user permissions to your users to access the billing information.